# Attaching a sheet the first time

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm writing an application which needs to read data off a smartcard. Due to the way smartcards work, this operation is likely to take a few seconds during which time it updates the display with what it's read so far, but isn't going to be fully responsive yet until everything's read; so, to avoid confusion, I want to show a sheet with a spinner and the text "Reading data from card..." so the user knows what's going on.

In my Xib, I've created a new window containing the spinner and an NSTextField. When I try to show the sheet, I do the following:

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    [_spinner startAnimation:self];
    [NSApp beginSheet:_CardReadSheet modalForWindow:_window modalDelegate:self 
           didEndSelector:@selector(endSheet:returnCode:contextInfo:) contextInfo:nil];
}];
```

and then later on, when my state machine indicates that we've finished reading, I do:

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    [NSApp endSheet:_CardReadSheet];
    [_spinner stopAnimation:self];
}];
```

There is also a

```
- (void) endSheet:(NSWindow*)sheet returnCode:(NSInteger)returnCode contextInfo:(void*)ctxInfo {
    [sheet orderOut:self];
}
```

where `_CardReadSheet` is the sheet I want to display, `_window` is my window to which I want to attach the sheet, and `_spinner` is the circular progress indicator.

This seems to work fine the **second** time; that is, if I start the application, read data off the card, remove the card from the reader, and then read it again, it works okay.

The first time around however, rather than showing it as a sheet attached to my main window, it shows the `CardReadSheet` as a top-level window on the location that seems to be specified in the xib file, and the `[sheet orderOut:self]` line has no effect (the window remains on-screen).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure it isn't visible at launch or some other weird option set

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem indeed; switched off "Visible At Launch" in the Xib, and now it's shown properly.

Comment: knew it - I struggled with the same issue for hours too :D

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint in your first block and see if _window is nil that first time through, I suspect it is. In my experience, these sorts of sheet commands display as a separate window when passed nil.

You might either make sure the window is displayed before adding the operation, or use self.window instead of _window. Self.window forces the window to be set up, although that can be tricky if you make assumptions elsewhere about when the window sets up.

Either way, note caveats for referencing self or ivars inside a block.